# How to specify which columns to read using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html file with a table inside it.  This table has 30 columns but I need to read only a few.

Code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("myfile.htm"))
table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class":"myTable"})

# The first tr contains the field names.
headings = [th.get_text() for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th")]

datasets = []
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    dataset = zip(headings, (td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")))
    datasets.append(dataset)

for dataset in datasets:
    for field in dataset:
        print "{0:<16}: {1}".format(field[0], field[1])
```

How may I specify which columns I want to read ?

Comment: Add the reason of your "vote for close". Thanks!

Comment: You question is too vague.  You need more details.  What is the format of the data that your looking for?  Are there id's for the td's you want? Which ones do you want?  Why are you grabbing all of the td's if you only want a couple.  Your code looks like you just copy pasted it from somewhere but you don't know how to modify it, and you question is sufficiently vague.

Comment: Could we have a look at the myfile.htm. You know, for science? ;D

Answer (score 1):

Option 1.  Use `table.find("tr").findNext()`

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html#find-all-next-and-find-next

Option 2. Use lxml in BeautifulSoup and provide xpath. 
[image: in Chrome]